# parser the xml and build a ui for user

Tags: java, xml, swing, xsd

Now I have to handle some xml in my java swing application.
I have to build a swing ui according to the special schema ,then user can fill some values.After user completed,I will collect the information,validate the value and then build a xml file.

For building xml file I can use the xmlbeans,however how to parse the schema and build a swing ui? Since the schema is rather complex.
A schema can be found here:

[example schema](http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsDescribeProcess_response.xsd)

I have to parser this schema,for the LiteralInputType ,a JTextArea should be built.
However there are other types "complexType" and etc..
These types may not occur at the sametime. Some times only the LiteralInputType is needed,somethimes the ComplexType is needed,also maybe all of them are needed.

So, how to implement it? Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting to see someone else busy with WPS. :)

I believe WPS is quite special so that no existing tool would be able to build user interfaces for WPS processes. When we were solving this task, we just took a [JAXB-based parser for WPS](https://ogc.dev.java.net/) and simply built the UI programmaticaly using factories. We've implemented Swing-based as well as Javascript/OpenLayers based generic WPS clients this way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your job.
However it seems that what you did is just related to how to handle the xml(parser and generate),however I used to use the xmlbeans to do this.
What I need is build swing ui according to the schema,however I did not find anthing about this in the website.
Than you any way.

Comment: I wasn't actually proposing a solution for you, I just shared our experience that WPS is quite special, so there are not ready tools for that.

Comment: OK,thanks, I know that. However use maven to manage these schema-jars is a good idea for people who working with maven.